# Object typecasting in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, types, casting

So, object typecasting in Objective C isn't a good practice (isn't a good design), and have to be use only if it's really needed .
TRUE or FALSE ?

Comment: It's hard to think of an example of *any* unnecessary code being considered a good practice. If you need it, use it; if not, save your breath.

Comment: `@interface SomeSubclassOfUIView : UIView`                    `UIView* uiView = [[UIView alloc] init];`        `SomeSubclassOfUIView* subClassObj = ;(SomeSubclassOfUIView*)uiView; `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typecasting objective c objects does not work at all, because there is no overloading of the cast operator as in c++.
So basically you can only safely typecast object which have common superclasses e.g. NSMutableString and NSString etc.

But you don't need to do this.

In general no need to typecast objc objects.

Comment: So object typecast in objc is dangerous and prone to make a mess ?